# How to create logic / find style for tr id in table

Tags: ajax

I've got a table defined as below:

```
<table id="DateTable" width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr id="prior" style="display: none;" ><td>
       . .. .. . prior
      </td></tr>
      <tr id="current"><td>
        . .. ..  current
      </td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to have logic put in place that determines if the   style="display: none;"   exists for the "prior" id.

I have this, but it doesn't work:

```
if($("#DateTable tr").find("prior").html("style=display: none;").length > 1)
    alert("Style exists!!");
}
else {
    alert("Style doesn't exist.");
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method:

```
if($("#DateTable tr").find("#prior").css("display") === 'none')
```

Also note that ID should be unique in DOM and you forget to add `#` symbol in your selector for `prior` element.

So your code can be simple:

```
if($("#prior").css("display") === "none") {
    alert("Style exists!!");
} else {
    alert("Style doesn't exist.");
}
```